# In Java, a small help to allow a program send commands to CMD.exe

Tags: java, cmd, command-line, operating-system, command

I am trying to create a program (personal practice) to access CMD and type any command you want, as if you were working on cmd.exe;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CMD_Live {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // The purpose of this program is to use Java to perform CMD commands as if you are working on it live

        Scanner ScanCMD = new Scanner(System.in); 

        while(true) {

            System.out.print("Insert your Command> ");
            String CMDcommand = ScanCMD.nextLine();

            Process processToCMD = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMDcommand);
            BufferedReader readerToCMD = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processToCMD.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = readerToCMD.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            System.out.println();
            readerToCMD.close();
        }

    }

}
```

> The problem with this code is, it works for straightforward commands,
>   like **ping google.com**, or **nslookup google.com**,
>
> but if I insert **nslookup** and hit enter to access advance mode, then the response goes off. 
>   Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Again using System.in.readLine at the end?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(CMDcommand); //note, that you can build your command here step by step.
Process process = processBuilder.start();
String response = null;

InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedInputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

//and then do whatever you want to do.. my example is this:
while(response=bufferedInputStream.readLine()!=null) {
    ..some code..
}
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```